# MySQL Stored Procedure works as plain SQL

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I'm trying to write a stored procedure that inserts into one table (A), then queries another table (B), then finally inserts into table (C) the last insert id, along with the result from table B.  I have written a stored procedure named VetIdFromCode to do the selecting from table B, which works fine in isolation.  When I run the query in isolation, subbing in value for the IN parameters then it runs fine, but when I try and save it as a stored procedure it tells me invalid SQL near 'SET @LIID...'
Many thanks for any help.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `NewClientUser`(
IN `uemail` VARCHAR(60), 
IN `uphash` CHAR(40), 
IN `uvcode` VARCHAR(11))
DETERMINISTIC 
MODIFIES SQL DATA 
SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
INSERT INTO users (user_id,user_email,user_hash,user_role) 
    VALUES (NULL,uemail,uphash,'1'); 
SET @LIID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
CALL `VetIdFromCode`(uvcode, @VID);
INSERT INTO user_vet_lookup(user_id,vet_id) 
    VALUES (@LIID,@VID);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to start the "code" of the procedure with the key word "BEGIN" and put an "END" at the end. Like:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `NewClientUser`(
IN `uemail` VARCHAR(60), 
IN `uphash` CHAR(40), 
IN `uvcode` VARCHAR(11))
BEGIN
    DETERMINISTIC 
    MODIFIES SQL DATA 
    SQL SECURITY INVOKER 
    INSERT INTO users (user_id,user_email,user_hash,user_role) 
        VALUES (NULL,uemail,uphash,'1'); 
    SET @LIID = LAST_INSERT_ID();
    CALL `VetIdFromCode`(uvcode, @VID);
    INSERT INTO user_vet_lookup(user_id,vet_id) 
        VALUES (@LIID,@VID);
END
```

Check out the documentation: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/create-procedure.html

Comment: Oh, you beat me to it xD  also `DELIMITER //   CREATE PROCEDURE.....END  //  DELIMITER ;`

Comment: Thanks.  I was doing it via phpMyAdmin and assumed it would add begin and end for me, and I must have an error elsewhere. Oops.